# Provisioning multiple vms with their own puppet environments

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I'm trying to provision two VMs out of a single `Vagrantfile`. My goal is to be able to spin up, say, a web server and a db server, apply some common configuration, then apply more specific configuration based whether the system is hosting data or websites. Obviously if I'm doing two static VMs this isn't an issue, but eventually the number of systems going up might be dynamic, so I'd like to figure this out first. Here's the gist of the `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.config(2) do |config|
    config.vm.provision :shell, inline: 'apt-get install -y -q puppet'
    config.vm.box = 'ubuntu/xenial64'

    config.vm.provision :puppet do |default_puppet|
        puppet.manifests_path = 'puppet/manifests'
        puppet.module_path = 'puppet/modules'
    end

    config.vm.define 'web' do |web|
        config.vm.provision :puppet do |web_puppet|
            web_puppet.environment_path = 'puppet/environments'
            web_puppet.environment = 'web'
        end
    end

    config.vm.define 'db' do |db|
        config.vm.provision :puppet do |db_puppet|
            db_puppet.environment_path = 'puppet/environments'
            db_puppet.environment = 'db'
        end
    end
end
```

I've got the following directory structure:

```
.
├── Vagrantfile
└── puppet
    ├── environments
    │   ├── db
    │   │   └── manifests
    │   │       └── default.pp
    │   └── web
    │       └── manifests
    │           └── default.pp
    ├── hiera.yaml
    ├── manifests
    │   └── default.pp
    └── modules
        ├── ntp
        └── stdlib
```

My `manifests/default.pp` is pretty simple:

```
# Set up some default stuff that both servers should have
class { '::ntp':
    servers => [
        '0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org',
        '1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org',
        '2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org',
        '3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org',
    ]
}

file { '/home/ubuntu/file0.txt':
    ensure  => file,
    content => 'should be available on all systems'
}
```

And the `/environments/{db,web}/manifests/default.pp` files are also pretty simple, basically just this:

```
# set up something specifically for the database server
file { '/home/ubuntu/file1.txt':
    ensure  => file,
    content => 'this file should only be on the db server.'
}
```

The filename and content is changed so it'll be obvious when looking at the directory that everything worked correctly.

This almost works - when I update `manifests/default.pp`, the changes are applied to both; and when I update `environments/web/manifests/default.pp` the `web` server gets those changes. But when I provision the `db` environment, it gets both environments:

```
==> web: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> web: Running Puppet with default.pp...
==> web: Info: Loading facts
==> web: Notice: Compiled catalog for web.vm in environment production in 0.64 seconds
==> web: Info: Applying configuration version '1481059856'
==> web: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/home/ubuntu/file0.txt]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}ba94d90e4b2e228b54c75d9110e3179c'
==> web: Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.07 seconds
==> web: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> web: Running Puppet with environment web...
==> web: Notice: Compiled catalog for web.vm in environment web in 0.12 seconds
==> web: Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.01 seconds

==> db: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> db: Running Puppet with default.pp...
==> db: Info: Loading facts
==> db: Notice: Compiled catalog for db.vm in environment production in 0.64 seconds
==> db: Info: Applying configuration version '1481059866'
==> db: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/home/ubuntu/file0.txt]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}ba94d90e4b2e228b54c75d9110e3179c'
==> db: Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.07 seconds

** shouldn't be doing this **
==> db: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> db: Running Puppet with environment web...
==> db: Notice: Compiled catalog for db.vm in environment web in 0.11 seconds
==> db: Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.01 seconds

** this is fine though **
==> db: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> db: Running Puppet with environment db...
==> db: Notice: Compiled catalog for db.vm in environment db in 0.12 seconds
==> db: Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.01 seconds
```

This happens when I run `vagrant provision`. Now, I've also discovered that if I run `vagrant provision db` only the `db` environment is applied...but shouldn't I be able to set environments per machine in a multi-machine `Vagrantfile`? Is there another way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

And then I realized that I was working in the same `config` namespace for both defined machines. Here's my tweaked `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.config(2) do |config|
    config.vm.provision :shell, inline: 'apt-get install -y -q puppet'
    config.vm.box = 'ubuntu/xenial64'

    config.vm.provision :puppet do |default_puppet|
        puppet.manifests_path = 'puppet/manifests'
        puppet.module_path = 'puppet/modules'
    end

    config.vm.define 'web' do |web|
        # now it's web.vm.provision, not config.vm.provision
        web.vm.provision :puppet do |web_puppet|
            web_puppet.environment_path = 'puppet/environments'
            web_puppet.environment = 'web'
        end
    end

    config.vm.define 'db' do |db|
        # now it's db.vm.provision, not config.vm.provision
        db.vm.provision :puppet do |db_puppet|
            db_puppet.environment_path = 'puppet/environments'
            db_puppet.environment = 'db'
        end
    end
end
```